# ASP.NET AJAX Client Templates - Jquery Equivalent

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax, client-templates

I've been looking at ASP.NET AJAX Client Templates.

My position is that I prefer to use Jquery rather than ASP.NET AJAX as I feel this will win the day in the long term.

Are there Jquery plugins/functionaility that provide the same kind of help for rendering that client templates do in ASP.NET AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Resig's (jQuery Creator) Microtemplating engine has worked very well for me with ASP.NET.

Rick Strahl has an excellent post on this that details using the Microtemplating engine with ASP.NET and compares it to other solutions at http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/509108.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET AJAX has some pros and cons as JQuery. You can use them together if you need powerful client-side library. Btw, if you can specify what you are after exactly, maybe we can help more.